# how get cookie as method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i get a `cookie` on `controller` and i want pass `cookie` to the `ChekLogin` method on 
    `login.cs` what is type of cookie on ChekLogin

```
public ActionResult test()
{
  Login.ChekLogin(Request.Cookies["Account"];
}
```

checklogin method

```
public static bool ChekLogin()// what is type of cookie
{
}
```

Comment: Why don't you search web first? I can't beleive there is no info in MSDN.

Comment: i search on web but i don't find anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Request.Cookies["Account"]` returns an [`HttpCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx), so that's the type your `CheckLogin` method could take as parameter:

```
public static bool ChekLogin(HttpCookie cookie)
{
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        string cookieValue = cookie.Value;
    }
}
```

Of course if the cookie is not present in the request, `Request.Cookies["Account"]` will return null, so make sure you take this into account in your `ChekLogin` method.

Also, just to ensure that you are not reinventing some wheels or opening your site to security risks, make sure you have read about [`Forms Authentication in ASP.NET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The type of one cookie is `HttpCookie`. (See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/38yh3s7x.aspx))

You can then access its value with `account.Value`.

You method would look like

```
public static bool ChekLogin(HttpCookie account)
{
    //...
}
```